# How to change Rails application config on a per-spec basis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Our Rails app has a custom 404 and 500 pages:

```
  match '/500', :to => 'errors#internal_server_error', :via => :all
```

And we have some specs to make sure it works.

In test.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.consider_all_requests_local     = false
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
end
```

However, during development exceptions are swallowed making it difficult figure out what is happening.

So, for some tests we need the above config, and other specs different config. But the config is set before the test runs so not able to update.

How to update the config for a single spec in a before block?

Rails 6

EDIT: What I've tried:

Shira mentioned mocking, but that does not appear to do anything.

```
Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local     = false
Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

This does work, but only before the first request. After the first request it does not do anything.

```
Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local     = ->{ ENV['...'] }
```

This does not work.

It seems that the issue is that these configs are used in the middleware and once the app is configured changes are not reflected.

I tried to find a way to re-initialize the Rails app, but it appears that there is no way to do it.

I guess the only way to do it is to monkey patch the middleware to use a Proc with an ENV...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ***does*** work:

```
Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions']          = true
Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] = false
```

Thanks to Eliot Sykes https://www.eliotsykes.com/realistic-error-responses

Comment: Following Eliot Sykes guide worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is possible to actually change the configuration but you can mock this configuration instead:

```
allow(Rails.application.config).to receive(:consider_all_requests_local).and_return(true)
```

Comment: I checked it in my spec and it worked. 
I saw that you found a solution, but maybe it will help others in the future.